# I always turn off the audio of the Koran when I hear music, so as not to desecrate its reading

Tags: quran

Assalyamu alaikum , is it correct to turn off the reading of the Koran while music is playing? music is prohibited and I can’t turn off other people’s music, so I turn off the Quran so that it doesn’t sound in parallel with it. Jazakallahu Khairan